# Get the input data from textarea of HTML and store that values in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, textbox, textfield

I want to extract the multiple data from textbox.
Suppose I enter following data into text field separated by space.

> 11 22 33 44 55 66

then it should separate the data from textbox and store that data in an array, say a.
If I say, I want to display value of first element array i.e. a[0], then it should display 11 and so on.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rayon's answer is correct and uses core javascript.

If you'd like to do it in jQuery you can chain commands like so:

```
var a = $('ta').val().split(' ');
```

If you then want to get the first number of the array, you could do:

```
a[0];
```

Where text area is:

```
<textarea name="ta" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10">11 22 33 44 55 66</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Use [**`str.split([separator[, limit]])`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

*The `split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.*

```js
var text = document.getElementById('ta').value;
console.log(text.split(' '));
```

```html
<textarea name="ta" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10">11 22 33 44 55 66</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the appropriate method split :->

```
String string = "11 22 33 44 55 66";
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
```